# How to get the window width and use it with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sorry if this very obvios however I am realy stuck.
I would like the window width when a user lands on a page and then use this to set a php variable.

I understand that I can't get the value by php so I did the following (this is all on one page)
**page.php**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready( function() {
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'width' : windowWidth, 'height' : windowWidth, 'recordSize' : 'true' },
        success: function(response) {
            $("body").html(response);
        }
    });
                // Resize Event
    $(window).resize(function(){

        // Check window width has actually changed and it's not just iOS triggering a resize event on scroll
        if ($(window).width() != windowWidth) {
 if ($(window).height() != windowHeight) {
            // Update the window width for next time
            windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowHeight = $(window).height();
            // Do stuff here
  $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
        data: { 'width1' : windowWidth, 'height1' : windowHeight, 'recordSize1' : 'true' },
        success: function(response) {
            $("body").html(response);
        }
    });
        }
        }
        // Otherwise do nothing

    });
    
    
});
</script>

<?php 
 if ($_POST['width1'] == ""){
    $width = $_POST['width'];}
else $width = $_POST['width1'];
  
    ?>
```

The $width is then used to determine the following on the page

```
<?php  if ($width < 481){ $max_columns = 2;} 
                    if (($width > 481)&&($width < 981)) {  $max_columns = 3;}
                            if ($width >981){ $max_columns = 4;}  ?>
```

This all works however the page seems to be reloading every time. Not only that if you validate the page with google it can't see any content on the page.

Somebody suggested to use Ajax XMLHttpRequest the problem is Im not sure how to use this.
Can anybody point me in the right direction.
Any help is welcome

Comment: What does "reloading every time" mean? Every time when what happens? And by reloading, do you mean an actual refresh or that AJAX is triggered?

Comment: @El_Vanja it reloads every time the screen is resize e.g turning from landscape to portrait

Comment: I'm lost. Isn't that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @El_Vanja I am sorry, I am trying to get the screen width without reloading the whole page so I can just use this to determine the $max_columns. The other problem is that for some reason the google validation can't see any contents when done this way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question should focus on one problem. So you're saying that it actually performs a full reload of the page instead of only replacing the contents by the means of AJAX?

Comment: @El_Vanja the problem with google is cause by this method that is why I'm hoping if somebody could help me suggesting an other way. Therefore it is 2 problems caused by one, I am sorry if that wasn't clear maybe you could suggest how to improve?

Comment: Use css `@media` queries and show/hide your extra columns via css

Comment: @freedomn-m I have tried this however the columns are in a table the max columns on a desktop is set to 4, but I dont think I can change the $max_columns with just css. Unless there is a way to not show the overflow columns. Thanks anyway

Comment: So if I visit your page it will be blank, then your JS kicks in, determines my browser size, sends that to the server, which responds with an appropriate number of columns, and if I resize, it erases everything again and repeats? Is that the general experience?

Comment: `<tr><td>col1</td><td class="col_landscape"></td><td class="col_landscape"></td></tr>` then an @media query which hides `.col_landscape` when it's not landscape.  This also means you can pick which columns are shown on landscape(more) vs portrait and not just cut off the end one(s).  Depends on what else you use `$max_columns` for - but if it's just for how many columns to show, then no need for it.

Comment: @freedomn-m that would work, however my table is created dynamically and I am not able I think to decide which column can not be shown. But I think it would make sense when you can put a class on the different columns. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Or you could just use the equivalent of `current_col>max_col ? "class='col_landscape'" : ""` if your table is data-driven